# UISegmentControl with UITableView - UITableViewCell layout remains same on changing the segment

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

In the scenario mentioned in the question title, on changing the segment, ideally the `UITableView` should reload and hence the `UITableViewCell` should also reload. The issue is, all the content gets updated like label texts. But if I have expanded a subview of cell in one segment, it remains still expanded after segment is changed.
Segment index change function :

```
@IBAction func segmentOnChange(sender: UISegmentControl)
{
    // Few lines
    // self.tableMenu.reloadData()
}
```

**Screenshot 1 :**

[image]

**Screenshot 2 :**

[image]

So ideally, in screenshot 2, the cart view should have been collapsed.

**Update :**

Show/Hide view :

```
func showHideCartView(sender: UIButton)
    {
        let cell = self.tableMenu.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: Int(sender.accessibilityHint!)!)) as! RestaurantMenuItemCell
        if sender.tag == 1
        {
            // Show cart view
            cell.buttonArrow.tag = 2
            cell.viewAddToCart.isHidden = false
            cell.constraint_Height_viewAddToCart.constant = 50
            cell.buttonArrow.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrowUp.png"), for: .normal)
        }
        else
        {
            // Show cart view
            cell.buttonArrow.tag = 1
            cell.viewAddToCart.isHidden = true
            cell.constraint_Height_viewAddToCart.constant = 0
            cell.buttonArrow.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrowDown.png"), for: .normal)
        }

        self.tableMenu.reloadData()
    }
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath :**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RestaurantMenuItemCell", for: indexPath) as! RestaurantMenuItemCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        let menuItem = self.menuItems[indexPath.section]
        cell.imageViewMenuItem.image = UIImage(named: "recommend0@2x.png")
        cell.labelName.text = menuItem.name
        cell.labelDescription.text = menuItem.description
        cell.labelPrice.text = String(format: "$%i", menuItem.price!)
        cell.buttonArrow.accessibilityHint = String(format: "%i", indexPath.section)
        cell.buttonArrow.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.showHideCartView(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: How you can expand your table cell ? means manage in heightForRowAtIndexPath Method ?

Comment: this should have an easy fix.. check your model, that determines if a cell is expanded or not.. you have to reset it on segment change

Comment: @iPatel : Through constraints. I have set estimatedRowHeight = 150 and rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: @MilanNosáľ : Updated my question with code

Comment: @Nitish check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you rely on the sender button's tag to determine whether the cell should be shown in expanded or collapsed state, you need to make sure that when the segment changes, the tags for all the cells' `buttonArrow` also change to 1.

Unless that happens, the cells will be reused and since the `buttonArrow`'s tag is set to 2, it will be shown as expanded.

Comment: I have now taken a model property for handing that.

Answer (score 1):

You are reusing cells, see first line of your `cellForRowAt` implementation:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RestaurantMenuItemCell", for: indexPath) as! RestaurantMenuItemCell
```

That means that a tableView does not create a new cell, nor it redraws it unless necessary for the given `indexPath`. However, in the code you expand a cell by setting some height constraints and `isHidden` flags on subviews of the cell. Now once you reload table at a new segment, the `tableView` will use the already rendered cells to make the reload as efficient as possible. However, that means, that although you will change the data in the cell, unless you explicitly collapse it, it will stay expanded (because previously you have set the constraints to expanded height).

You need to reset the expanded state when you change the segment. Now let's elaborate, because I believe your current solution has a hidden bug in it:

First of all, since as I said you are dequeueing the cells, in case there are a lot of items in the table and you are scrolling through them, there is a high chance that the expanded cell will get reused even somewhere later in the table view. So it will seem like there is some random item expanded too.

Therefore I suggest you to provide some model that would remember which cells are supposed to be expanded and then use the information in this model to update state of each cell before you return them in your `cellForRowAt`. The model can be for example a simple array of integer values that would represent indexes of cells that are expanded - so for example if there is an index 3 in the array, that would mean that cell at row 3 should be expanded. Then when you dequeue a cell in `cellForRowAt` for `indexPath` with row = 3 you should set constraints on that cell before returning it. This way you can remove the bug I mentioned. Moreover, then when you change segments, you can just remove all the indexes from the array to signify that no cell should be expanded anymore (do it before calling `tableView.reloadData()`).

Answer (score 0):

What happened here, When you click any row then It will be expanded based on make true first condition in `showHideCartView` method and after that when you are changing segment index that keep height of previous row as it is because you are reusing cell So you must set normal hight of each row when you change segment index.

For do that take object of `indexPath` like

```
var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath?
```

Then set `selectedIndexPath` in `showHideCartView` method

```
func showHideCartView(sender: UIButton) {
  selectedIndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: Int(sender.accessibilityHint!)!)) // you can change row and section as per your requirement.

 //// Your other code
}
```

Then apply below logic whenever you are changing segment index.

```
@IBAction func segmentOnChange(sender: UISegmentControl)
{
        if indexPath = selectedIndexPath { // check selectedIndexPath is not nil
          let cell = self.tableMenu.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! RestaurantMenuItemCell
          cell.buttonArrow.tag = 1
          cell.viewAddToCart.isHidden = true
          cell.constraint_Height_viewAddToCart.constant = 0
          cell.buttonArrow.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrowDown.png"), for: .normal)
        }

    selectedIndexPath = nil // assign nil to selectedIndexPath
    // Few lines

  self.tableMenu.reloadData()  // Reload your tableview

}
```